# Fixed value every N months BUT with a specific start month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to schedule a fixed amount every 3 months BUT I want to specify when the first month should be.

I could get the scheduling to work every 3 months with the following formula where `F5` is the interval and `G5` is the amount:

```
=IF(MOD(MONTH(H2)-1,$F$5)=0,$G$5,0)
```

I believe the offset of -1 is the problem but I don't know how to replace the offset for the start date that I specify.

[image: Example of formula and expected result]

How do I start the schedule from 1/2/2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to repeat the fixed amount every 3 months, but you want to customize start date.

I got this:

[image]

My formula:

```
=IF(D1>=$A$2;IF(MOD(MONTH(D1)-MONTH($A$2);3)=0;$B$2;"");"")
```

My logic. If you want to make sure the date is every 3 months starting on your start date, it means that the difference between the month of start date and month of date must be 0, 3 or multiples of 3.

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I will try and adapt it to mu scenario and see if it solves my problem

Comment: I tried to apply this formula to my data but I can't get it to work. The formula doesn't want to resolve at all

Comment: Edit your question and post the formula you have tried when copying mine please.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to schedule a fixed value every N period starting from a specific date.

I used the suggested answer and the formula

=IF(D2>=$A$6,IF(MOD(MONTH(D2)-MONTH($A$6),$B$6)=0,$C$6,0),0)

[Example applicable to the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djysp.png)

Comment: Nice! So you could adapt it to your needs. Great!